# How to create a static view

Tags: ios, uiview

I am trying to create a music player which will be available in all my view controller scenes at the bottom. I have designed all my scenes using storyboard and I have them embedded in a UINavigationController. Am trying to achieve same technic which spotify have used to display the player at the bottom no matter which page you are on. I have created a AudioPlayerView controller subclassing UIViewController and implemented my music functionalities like playing and pause but now am stuck on how I can have that player included in the scenes and always be available no matter which scenes the user navigates to. I will really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure there are myriad ways to accomplish this. I'd recommend using a custom container controller, which has the music player at the bottom and a navigation controller (which contains the rest of your app's controllers) above that.

You should take a look at the **Presenting Another View Controller’s Content** section of Apple's [UIViewController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).